# Fixed Point in a random positive integer function

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

I was talking with a friend this morning and he asked me this problem:
For a random positive integer function ( from N to N) What is the possibility that the function contains a fixed point, i.e. f(x)=x

Without knowledge of measure theory, I do not think the problem is well defined, though it is supposedly an “equal chance” model.

The problem with this definition is that, if we consider functions of set {1,2,...,n} to N we can inductively get a possibility of 0 ( Not so sure, here is what I did: say g(n) is the possibility from all functions from set 1 to n, base case g(1)=0, and of g(n)=0, g(n+1)=g(n)+g(1)=0

Yet similarly, if we consider the functions from {1,...,n} to {1 to n} we will get 1/e eventually.

Can someone point out flaw in each reasoning?
Merry Christmas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ is a random function then questions arise as: what is the probability that $f(0)=n$?

Evidently it cannot be that this probability is the same for every $n\in\mathbb N$ so there is no uniform distribution available for $f(0)$.

That means that random functions $\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ can only exist by the grace of predefined distributions that cannot be recognized as uniform.

A sort of "canonical" uniform distribution as we have on finite sets or on intervals $[a,b]$ lacks.

This makes questions like: "what is the probability that a random positive integer function has a fixed point?" senseless.

Answers on the question are bound to distributions and there are lots of them.

For different distributions we get different answers.

Comment: Hi, thanks! That is what I thought with a formal notion. After reviewing probability axioms, I might just show the conflict that no uniform distribution exists